# Is it possible to query if a particular namespace exists?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to detect 3rd party configuration un-intrusively by checking which namespaces exist.

I suppose I can just check for a specific parameter in said namespace, but that feels a little wrong/less robust than checking for the namespace directly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10085/is-it-possible-to-query-if-a-particular-namespace-exists?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Parameters, topics, services, and nodes can all create namespaces.  The only way to robustly check for a namespace is to

1. Query for the parameter
2. Parse the result from rosgraph.masterapi.Master.getSystemState()

It would be better, though, I think, for your 3rdparty configuration to more explicitly declare its presence (e.g. via parameter, or topic, or otherwise).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2